# Permission issue with PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am using a CMS. when I put HTML code it works, when I put simple PHP code like "hello World" or when I try to connect to a database it works. But when I put more complex PHP code like " phpinfo()"  or any SQL statements like `"$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM insription_14juin');"` it doesn't work. The message that I get using fiddler is

```
 403 Forbidden
 You don't have permission to access /admin/modules/gestion_articles/updateContenu.php
on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

After multiple tests I think that a JavaScript file is trying to load information into a PHP file and apparently when the PHP code is complex the JavaScript file doesn't have permission to access the PHP file.

This is the JavaScript file:

```
  $(function() {
$('#savemodif').click(function() {
    $('#formModif').append('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Enregistrement en cours..." id="loadingImg" />');

            var contenu ="";
    var type = $('#type').val();
    if(type == '0')
    {
                tinyMCE.triggerSave();
                contenu = $('#contenu').val();
                contenu = encodeURIComponent(contenu);
    }
    else
    {
                contenu = $('#contenu').val();
                contenu = encodeURIComponent(contenu);
    }

    /* Récupération d'infos nécessaires à la mise à jour */
    var id = $('#idcontenu').val();
    var oldtitre = $('#oldtitre').val();

    /* Récupération des mises à jours */
    var titre = $('#titre').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var publie = 0; if($('#publie').is(':checked')) publie = 1;
            var diapo = '0'; if($('#diapo').is(':checked')) diapo = '1';
    var prive = 0; if($('#prive').is(':checked')) prive = 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'modules/gestion_articles/updateContenu_test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'id='+encodeURIComponent(id)
            + '&oldtitre='+encodeURIComponent(oldtitre)
            + '&titre='+encodeURIComponent(titre)
            + '&date='+encodeURIComponent(date)
            + '&contenu='+contenu
            + '&publie='+encodeURIComponent(publie)
            + '&diapo='+encodeURIComponent(diapo)
                            + '&prive='+encodeURIComponent(prive),

        success: function(result) {
            $('#result').html(result);
            $('#loadingImg').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });

    $('#oldtitre').attr('value',titre);

    return false;
});
  });
```

I already tried changing permissions in cpanel, it doesn't work. I renamed every htaccess file, it doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you run **any** PHP code independent of that file *(a file like `<?php phpinfo();`)*? What permissions have you tried? Is the owner of the file `nobody` or your cPanel user?

Comment: I don't understand why `phpinfo()` is more complex than database connections, but @Deefour is right - try to run an independent file through the browser.

Comment: yes i can when i put a php file wihout using the cms it works fine because i just have to put it via cpanel not via the cmms so it doesnt use the file updateContenu.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is finally solved, it was about modsecurity. The technician told me that there was a restriction in modsecurity. If you are having the same problem check this with your provider.

The code I posted above works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is permissions on your file system. I'm assuming that you are not the server admin.

Send your server admin an email saying what is happening and he'll take a look into it and change permissions around.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but I've encountered a similar message on my cms whenever there is a placeholder file missing from the server folder of the page.  Like a index.php or something.

Another thing might be to add

```
async: false,
```

to your ajax call to make sure it is running with the appropriate data.